# How to fix windows 8 startup black screen?

Tags: windows-8

**Issue:** I have a Dell laptop on which I have installed windows 8 but the problem is whenever I start the laptop, it behaves normally until after windows logo screen with loading circle beneath it. When that screen fades out, a black screen fades in.

**Workaround:**
I hit the power button, it sleeps and when I press power button once again, it works and the desktop appears.

*Question:* **Why does it happen and how to fix that?**

Comment: does windows update processed by non -admin users?it might be occur due to improper installation of drivers

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2850674/en-us Are all Update installed?

Comment: Do you use internet user? Is internet connected at that time??

Comment: Have you tried troubleshooting using the windows 8 recovery mode?

Answer (score 0):

If you could enable boot logging it may help to understand the problem. You can enable it via Startup Settings.

The ways to reach Startup Settings screen in Windows 8 is explained in the [official site](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode) as follows:

> There are two ways to get to the Windows Startup Settings screen in
>   Windows 8 :
>
> - If you're not signed in to Windows, tap or click the power icon  from the sign-in screen, hold Shift, and then tap or click Restart
> - Or, if you're already signed in:
>
>   1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, tap Settings, and then tap Change PC settings. (If you're using a mouse, point to the
>        upper-right corner of the screen, move the mouse pointer down, click
>        Settings, and then click Change PC settings.)
>   2. Under PC settings, tap or click General.
>   3. Under Advanced startup, tap or click Restart now.
>   4. On the Choose an option screen, tap or click Troubleshoot.
>   5. Tap or click Startup Settings.
>   6. Tap or click Restart.
>   7. On the Startup Settings screen, choose the startup setting you want.
>   8. Sign in to your PC with a user account that has administrator rights.

Once you enable boot logging, Windows 8 creates a file, ntbtlog.txt, that lists all the drivers that are installed during startup and that might be useful for advanced troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Clean install, genuine Windows, happening with both Windows 8 and 8.1, fully updated. It was fixed by installing the [recommended BIOS update from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN116332/EN) (in my case [Dell Inspiron N4050 System BIOS](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=GJ8JD)).

Download the executable, close all programs and let it run. It takes a few minutes to flash the BIOS and your computer will be abruptly restarted at the end, but the problem should be gone.

Took me years to find this solution because I assumed the Windows logo was proof it wasn't a BIOS problem.